# How to setup NLog to show sqlexception linenumber in log?

Tags: .net, sql-server, nlog

I have a stored procedure which can generate an error.
However, NLog writes only text message like that

> 16:08:37.7139|ERROR|ConsoleApplication35.Program|System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   (0x80131904): Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data
>   type int.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

But `SqlException` also has a `LineNumber` property

How to force NLog to write also line number?
Is there any predefined layout?

Comment: post your code that calls nlog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

You could use the format `@` ( NLog 4.5+)

```
${exception:format=@}
```

See [docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Exception-Layout-Renderer)

> format - Format of the output. Must be a comma-separated list of exception properties: Message, Type, ShortType, ToString, Method, StackTrace, Data & `@`. This parameter value is case-insensitive. Default: message
>
> `@` means serialize all Exception-properties into Json-format. Introduced in NLog 4.5

**note**: it would be possible it is also available when using "toString" format:

```
${exception:format=ToString}
```

### Option 2

If you need more control of the output, e.g. only the linenumber, you could write your own layout renderer (inherit from `ExceptionLayoutRenderer`):

```cs
 private class MyExceptionLayoutRenderer : ExceptionLayoutRenderer {

     protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
     {
         base.Append(builder, logEvent);

         // Also write linenumber (C# 7 syntax) at the end.
         if (logEvent.Exception is SqlException sqlException)
         {
             builder.AppendLine($"LineNumber: " + sqlException.LineNumber);
         }
     }
  
 }
```

and register it as soon as possible (e.g. app_start, main()):

```cs
LayoutRenderer.Register<MyExceptionLayoutRenderer>("myException"); //usage ${myException}
```

### Option 3

NLog 4.6.8 introduces the new Format-option `Properties`:

```
${exception:format=Message,Properties}
```